# Why are local field potentials generally band-pass filtered?

Tags: electrophysiology, signal-processing

I was wondering what the rationale was behind low-pass or band-pass filtering in local field potential measurements?

It seems to me that we could potentially filter out potentially valuable information by filtering procedures.

Is there a physical limitation for this that would not allow to measure, say, the responses in a frequency range of 0 to 5 kHz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no physical limitation whatsoever on the frequency band you wish to record, other than the hardware limitations on the [sampling rate](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Sample_Rates).

Often electrophysiological recordings suffer from [noise](http://www.ifsc.usp.br/~reynaldo/eletronica_instrumentacao/axon-guide/GuideCh12.pdf) (mainly in the high-frequencies) and [drifts in the baseline](https://uncch.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/a-baseline-stabilizer-for-electrophysiology) (low-frequency range).

In the end, you wish to filter out as much noise as possible, without throwing away the baby with the bathwater. In effect, **prior knowledge about the frequency range of the responses of interest** are vital. **Anything outside that range can, and likely should be filtered out**.

For example, [FFT analysis](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/) of [EEGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) mainly focuses on bands limited to the frequency range of 1 to 50 Hz. The mains frequency is 50 or 60 Hz, often imposing sinusoidal noise when the room is not shielded. Hence, what reason would there be not to use a low-pass filter with a cutoff around 50 Hz to get rid of it?

Lastly, offline filtering methods are aplenty. My *personal* preference nowadays is, is to collect the **raw data and filter offline**. That way you have the baby and the water, and you can focus, with trial and error, on where the baby is and where the water.

Comment: Coming to my rescue once more!

Comment: This is a nice answer. I remember an EE prof. who said a lab procedure they used to give grad students required them to recognize that noise from florescent lights would ruin their results unless filtered.